# How can I install vpfit on a 64 bit macOS?

Tags: macos, install

I am trying to install the Voigt profile fitting ([vpfit](https://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/%7Erfc/vpfit.html)) program on a 64 bit macOS machine.

I'm stuck on this. Kindly help if anyone had any luck with the installation.

Here is what I did:

***Port Install pgplot - [https://guaix.fis.ucm.es/~ncl/howto/howto-pgplot](https://guaix.fis.ucm.es/%7Encl/howto/howto-pgplot) (This part is working)**

```
sudo port install xorg-server
sudo port install pgplot
sudo port -f activate libgcc9
```

- • After the installation, make sure that the expected environment variables are properly set (at least PGPLOT_DIR must exist;
  PGPLOT_DEV is also quite useful). One can check this by executing:
  echo $PGPLOT_DIR
  echo $PGPLOT_DEV

**Install Cfitsio - This part is working**

```
sudo port install cfitsio +gcc7
```

**Install VPFIT - THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK**

- Go to working directory you are working out of (my case Downloads)
  mkdir vpfit
  cd vpfit
  wget [http://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~rfc/vpfit10.4.tar.gz](http://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/%7Erfc/vpfit10.4.tar.gz)
  tar -xvf vpfit10.4.tar.gz vpfit

• Edit makefile

cfitsx =        /usr/local/lib/cfitsio.a

pgpltx =        /usr/local/lib//libpgplot.a

- make vpmac

*I am getting undefined symbols for architecture*

Comment: I assume by the port you are using Macports - if so please note in question. If you are using Macports then what it installs in in /opt/local so what are the files thjat you have in /usr/local ?

Answer (score -1):

I had the errors *undefined symbols for architecture 86_x64* and fixed it by adding the libraries *-lcurl* and *-lz* in the line 182 of the makefile

```
PGLIB=-L/usr/local/lib -lpgplot -lX11 -lcurl -lz
```